# php add json data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and to add json data I am using following code.

```
function back_up($id){

$this->db->select("startTime, endTime, day, contact_id, people_id, type, editName, editTime, editId, comment, uuid, motif");
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$data = $this->db->get('table')->row_array();

$json_data = json_encode($data);
$udata = array('editHistory' => $json_data);

$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->update('table', $udata);
}
```

When I run this function it just display encoded json data, but database is not updated.
How can I add json to database

Comment: Do you get any MySQL errors?

Comment: no mysql error displayed

Comment: Hang on, you are inserting a PHP array into your database, i expect it just shows 'Array' in the database field right?

Comment: Are you only keeping track of the last change? Also are you really saving the data back to the same table? also try adding these lines to the top of your function to make sure you are seeing all errors error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: @Edward CI actually does not insert the PHP array it's inserting json_data into a field called editHistory.

Comment: @mschuett ok, I take it CI query functions only accept arrays, makes sense I suppose.

Comment: nothing is displayed, in database field. And no error displayed

Comment: @meda: One example I have encountered where it was useful saving json into a database column instead of attempting to create columns for every key, is for style/css information. If you don't know which of the many, many possible css property declarations need to be saved beforehand, you cannot easily create columns for each property. Also, statistics on specific css properties are not something you typically need to be able to select from a table.  There are also other similar cases I have found where it makes sense to store some variable user/account-related preferences as json.

Comment: most of the time it means you are doing something wrong, mysql fields are not meant to hold json data, If you face this situation you should instead create a table and link it also you should consider using better tools such as mongoDB

Comment: You may need to wrap your json data in serialize(); but at this point you are really looking into an issue with how your db is setup as mentioned above. Pending this Please post more info such as the DB schema a var_dump of $json_data and a dump of $this->db->last_query(); after you called update as all options based of what you have posted have been exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in phpMyAdmin editHistory column is text, not number.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the mysql data type for 'editHistory' in your 'table' table through phpMyAdmin to LONGTEXT for JSON storage

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the definition of json_encode function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You will see the out put is like this in Example 1:

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

I meant it has " inside the string.

Furthermore, if you see the definition of $this->db->update of codeigniter:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

You will see it mentions:

**Note: All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.**

I think it is the reason of your problem now.

Try to fix that.

Never try but i think you can try to use

$this->db->set(); instead of $this->db->update();

it may allow you to set the third parameter to not automatically escape data